# What if there is a tie in a House election in Iowa?

Tags: united-states, election, house-of-representatives, iowa

In Iowa's second district, there was a race settled by exactly six votes. The Republican candidate, Marianette Miller-Meeks defeated Democratic candidate Rita Hart in a very close election. Let's say there were six more votes cast for Rita Hart (or six fewer votes for Miller-Meeks, etc), or there was another recount which resulted in a tie. Then what would happen?

Note: I am asking this because there is another challenge being filed by the losing candidate, saying that there are 22 ballots found that her campaign believes were predominantly in her favor. If this challenge is accepted, it is plausible that a tie happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Iowa Secretary of State, Candidate FAQ, [What occurs if the election results in a tie?](https://sos.iowa.gov/elections/candidates/faq.html#10)

> Generally, when a tie occurs between two candidates, lots are drawn (i.e. a name is pulled out of a hat) to determine the winner.

In Election Laws of Iowa 2020,

[50.44 Tie vote.](https://www.legis.iowa.gov/docs/publications/EL/1151493.pdf#page=237)

> If more than the requisite number of persons, including presidential electors, are found to
> have an equal and the highest number of votes, the election of one of them shall be determined
> by lot. The name of each of such candidates shall be written on separate pieces of paper, as
> nearly uniform in size and material as possible, and placed in a receptacle so that the names
> cannot be seen. In the presence of the board of canvassers, one of them shall publicly draw
> one of such names, and such person shall be declared elected. The result of such drawing
> shall be entered upon the abstract of votes and duly recorded, and a certificate of election
> issued to such person, as provided in this chapter.